# as --32 to assemble 32-bit code doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, clang, 32-bit

I've created a simple Bootable OS. Now I want to run the Makefile with make to get a binary. I'm using MacOS, and downloaded Nasm and other tools with Homebrew. The Makefile is down below:

```
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o
%.o: %.cpp
        g++ $(GPPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
        ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
        sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
        mkdir iso
        mkdir iso/boot
        mkdir iso/boot/grub
        cp $< iso/boot/
        echo 'set timeout-0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        echo 'set default-0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        echo 'menuentry "My Operating System"{' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        echo ' boot' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        echo '}' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
        grub-mkrescue --output=$@ iso
        rm -rf iso

run: mykernel.iso
        (killall VirtualBox && sleep 1) || true
        VirtualBox --startvm "My Operating System" &
```

So I want to run this Makefile on MacOS Mojave Terminal with `Run` but I got an clang error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--32'
make: *** [loader.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Apparently your assembler doesn't support the `--32` option. Either it doesn't support 32 bit at all, or the option is called something else. Consult the documentation or help. E.g. on linux `as --help` prints `--32/--64/--x32         generate 32bit/64bit/x32 code`

Comment: On MacOS, `as` is I think clang in disguise, just like gcc is also actually `clang`.  Oh, and you can see that from the `as` error message prefixed with `clang:`.  It might support `-m32` like the clang frontend does for asm source files.  (Does clang on MacOS Catalina still support 32-bit object files at all?)

Comment: The latest macOS version has removed support for 32 bit code.  It could be that they also removed all support from the toolchain.

Comment: I am still using Mojave not Catalina